# Any Idea why I am getting these ERRORS after resolving all jar lib addition

Tags: servlets, icefaces, myeclipse

This is what I see on browser after building web app using Myeclipse 9.1

> HTTP Status 404 - /na77/

---

type Status report

> message /na77/
>
> description The requested resource (/na77/) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.13

The Stack Trace is below..

```
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/na77]
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/na77] has not been started
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:930)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1774)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate context initialization parameter javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addParameter(StandardContext.java:2303)
    ... 32 more
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/na77/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate context initialization parameter javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2752)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1061)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1774)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 49 column 19
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
21-Dec-2016 14:50:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/na77] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: I see you've already received an answer but it would help to know what you've done in response to the errors shown in the stack trace (duplicate Duplicate context initialization parameter javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE). Without that info, it seems that all you've done is post the error and stack trace without any investigation, hoping someone else will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If both JavaServer Faces and Visual Web JavaServer Faces are included then it results in web.xml where the property is duplicated.please check the web.xml